# React Native e2e testing + Detox: Second keyboard test fails, even though first one succeeds

Tags: react-native, keyboard, ios-simulator, detox

**Description:**
I'm currently writing my e2e tests for my React Native application using Detox. The tests are getting executed on the ios simulator.

Here are my tests:

```
import { ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_CREDENTIALS_TITLE } from "../app/config/constants/errorMessages";

describe("email login", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it("should have a logo", async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id("ordersome_logo"))).toBeVisible();
  });

  it("should be able to successfully log in", async () => {
    await element(by.id("email_input")).typeText("test@test.test");
    await element(by.id("password_input")).typeText("correctpassword");
    await element(by.id("submit_button")).tap();
    await expect(element(by.id("homescreen_text"))).toHaveText("HomeScreen");
  });

  it("should show an alert if the password or username is wrong", async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id("email_input"))).toBeVisible();
    await element(by.id("email_input")).typeText("test@test.test");
    await element(by.id("password_input")).typeText("wrongpassword");
    await element(by.id("submit_button")).tap();
    await expect(element(by.text(ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_CREDENTIALS_TITLE))).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

The first test passes successfully. Detox opens the keyboard, puts in the credentials and the application logs in. Then Detox reloads the app (just like described by the `beforeEach()`. Then the second test immediatly fails with the following error:

```
Failed: [Error: Error: An action failed. Please refer to the error trace below.
    Exception with Action: {
      "Action Name" : "Type 'test@test.test'",
      "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('email_input')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollVie
w'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((re
spondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('email_input')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))"
    }


    Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description" : "Failed to type string 'test@test.test', because keyboard was not shown on screen.",
        "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code" : "2",
        "File Name" : "GREYKeyboard.m",
        "Function Name" : "+[GREYKeyboard typeString:inFirstResponder:error:]",
        "Line" : "185"
      }
    ]]
```

What is the reason for this? Why does the first test succeed (after disabling the hardware keyboard) and the second one fail?

- Detox: 8.00
- React Native: 0.56
- Node: 9.4.0
- Device: iPhone X
- Xcode: 9.4.1
- macOS: High Sierra 10.13.4

### Edit

I found a workaround. If I tap the input in the second keyboard test first it works. I would still be interested in a "real" answer if any one knows what's up :)

Here is the workaround:

```
it("should show an alert if the password or username is wrong", async () => {
    await element(by.id("email_input")).tap();
    await element(by.id("email_input")).typeText("test@test.test");
    ...
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Not sure what is causing it, but I used the workaround you provided to fix it. Hopefully we can get to the bottom of this issue.